# Saving Problems in ImagePlus

Tags: java, imagej

I'm trying to change bit depth of a gray-scale image to 16-bit in Java. This is my source code. Though original gray-scale image is converted to 16-bit, after saving it in the PC, bit depth of that saved image is the same size of original image not the converted one (16-bit). How can I fix this problem. Thank You.

```
public class ImageConverter {
    private ImagePlus imp;
    private int type;
    private static boolean doScaling = true;

    /** Construct an ImageConverter based on an ImagePlus object. */
    public ImageConverter(ImagePlus imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
        this.type = imp.getType();
        System.out.println(imp.getType());
    }

    /** Convert your ImagePlus to 16-bit grayscale. */
    public ImagePlus convertToGray16() {
        System.out.println(this.imp.getBitDepth());
        if (this.type==ImagePlus.GRAY16)
            return imp;
        if (!(this.type==ImagePlus.GRAY8||this.type==ImagePlus.GRAY32||this.type==ImagePlus.COLOR_RGB))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported conversion");
        ImageProcessor ip = imp.getProcessor();
        imp.trimProcessor();
        Calibration cal = imp.getCalibration();
        //imp.setProcessor(null, ip.convertToFloat());
        imp.setProcessor(null, ip.convertToShort(doScaling));
        imp.setCalibration(cal); //update calibration
        return imp;
    }

    /** Set true to scale to 0-255 when converting short to byte or float
        to byte and to 0-65535 when converting float to short.
     * @param scaleConversions */
    public static void setDoScaling(boolean scaleConversions) {
        doScaling = scaleConversions;
        IJ.register(ImageConverter.class); 
    }

    /** Returns true if scaling is enabled.
     * @return  */
    public static boolean getDoScaling() {
        return doScaling;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
         ImagePlus i=new ImagePlus("D:\\grayScaleImage.bmp");
         ImageConverter ic=new ImageConverter(i);
         i=ic.convertToGray16();
         //BufferedImage imgBuffer=i.getProcessor().getBufferedImage(); 

         //System.out.println(imgBuffer);
         System.out.println(i.getBitDepth());
         //***********************************************//
         //problem here-though bit depth of converted image is 32, after saved in the PC, size becomes the original image size         
         FileSaver fs=new FileSaver(i);
         boolean result=fs.saveAsBmp("D:\\grayScaleImage_32.bmp");

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear, are you passing in a 16 bit image and expecting the resulting 16 bit image to be different? Have you confirmed that `convertToGray16()` is being called and getting past the short circuits?

Comment: No, I need to convert any bit of grayscale image (8 or 16 or 32 or any other) into 16 bit image.Yes I called that method in main method (ImagePlus i=new ImagePlus("D:\\grayScaleImage.bmp");
         ImageConverter ic=new ImageConverter(i);
         i=ic.convertToGray16();)

Comment: So did you check if `i.getType() == ImagePlus.GRAY16` after your conversion? Maybe the problem is with saving: many formats only support 8-bit data, or ImageJ converts them during saving... The best place to ask questions like this is the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: yes, I checked it. It is working. Up to the converting part it works fine. Only the saving part gives the trouble. Thank you for your information. @JanEglinger

Answer (score 0):

ImageJ's `BMP_Writer` class (which gets called by [`FileSaver`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/io/FileSaver.html)) seems to only support 8-bit and 24-bit (RGB) images.

When saving any grayscale image, it applies the current 8-bit lookup table (LUT) and always saves 8-bit. See the source code here:

https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/master/ij/plugin/BMP_Writer.java#L63-L81

---

You might want to try using [SCIFIO](https://imagej.net/SCIFIO) or [Bio-Formats](https://imagej.net/Bio-Formats) for saving instead (although I didn't check if they support any other bit depth).

Also, instead of [copy-pasting](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/8aca41cc8f2f2b6a368d74be2de4180e1ec54fd3/ij/process/ImageConverter.java#L49-L63) code from ImageJ 1.x, you can simply depend on the [ImageJ Ops](https://imagej.net/ImageJ_Ops) library to do your conversion. Here's a simple [Groovy script](https://imagej.net/Groovy_Scripting) (using [script parameters](https://imagej.net/Script_Parameters) and runnable from the [script editor](https://imagej.net/Using_the_Script_Editor)) illustrating this:

```groovy
#@ OpService ops
#@ Img inputImage

result = ops.run("convert.uint16", inputImage)
```

Comment: Thank You for all your assistance.